# Why does this code throws a ClassCastException If it is supposed **change** returns a Int[] using Generics

Tags: java, generics

This is the code: A simple Generic class and trying to change a value of an object:

```
public class PruebaGenerico5<T> {
   T [] aa = (T []) new Object[2];
    public PruebaGenerico5(T x, T y) {
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y; 
        System.out.println( aa[0]+" "+aa[1]); //OK
    }
    public T[] change(T x, T y) {
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y;
        return aa;
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        PruebaGenerico5<Integer> ll = new PruebaGenerico5<>(1,2);
        Integer[] foo = ll.change(12, 13); // throws ClassCastException
    }
}
´´´
```

Comment: Please don't ask the exact same question a second time. The first time you asked, you got some amazing answers.

Comment: (@rzwitserloot even if you do say so yourself ;p)

Comment: @AndyTurner There are at least 3 very good answers on the original. I'll leave it as a fun exercise to identify the 3 :P

Answer (score 0):

While an `Integer[]` is an `Object[]`, an `Object[]` is not an `Integer[]`.

By writing `T [] aa = (T []) new Object[2];`, you create an `Object[]` and not an `Integer[]` and this will stay being an `Object[]` no matter what type you assign it to.

As generics are erased at compile-time, the line `Integer[] foo = ll.change(12, 13);` casts the variable `aa` to `Inteter[]` resulting in the exception.

You can fix it by passing the actual array in the constructor:

```java
public class PruebaGenerico5<T> {
   T [] aa;
    public PruebaGenerico5(T[] aa) {
        System.out.println( aa[0]+" "+aa[1]); //OK
    }
    public T[] change(T x, T y) {
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y;
        return aa;
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        PruebaGenerico5<Integer> ll = new PruebaGenerico5<>(new Integer[]{1,2});
        Integer[] foo = ll.change(12, 13);
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to use reflection for creating the array.

```java
public class PruebaGenerico5<T> {
   T [] aa;
    public PruebaGenerico5(T x, T y) {
        try{
            aa=(T[])x.getClass().arrayType().getDeclaredConstructor(int.class).newInstance(2);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y; 
        System.out.println( aa[0]+" "+aa[1]); //OK
    }
    public T[] change(T x, T y) {
        aa[0]=x; aa[1]=y;
        return aa;
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        PruebaGenerico5<Integer> ll = new PruebaGenerico5<>(1,2);
        Integer[] foo = ll.change(12, 13);
    }
}
```

A third way to solve this problem is to use `List`s instead of arrays:

```java
public class PruebaGenerico5<T> {
    List<T> aa;
    public PruebaGenerico5(T x, T y) {
        aa=Arrays.asList(x,y);//elements can be overwritten but no elements can be added
        System.out.println( aa.get(0)+" "+aa.get(1)); //OK
    }
    public List<T> change(T x, T y) {
        aa.set(0,x);
        aa.set(1,y);
        return aa;
    }
    static public void main(String[] args) {
        PruebaGenerico5<Integer> ll = new PruebaGenerico5<>(1,2);
        List<Integer> foo = ll.change(12, 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I replace the code **Integer[] foo = ll.change(12, 13);** in the originalcode by **Integer [] cc = {1,2}; ll.aa = cc;** this works, why?

Comment: @Oscar for the reasons I explained when I answered your previous question: a cast is inserted in the first case to ensure that `ll.change(...)` really returns an `Integer[]`; but it doesn't need to make sure that the current value of `ll.aa` is an`Integer` in the second case because it overwrites it.

Comment: `T` will be converted to `Object` and an invisible cast is added when getting the return code of `change`. `Integer[] cc={1,2}` does not have this invisible cast.